# Hide Site page title in modern view

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, modern-pages

I'm working on a SharePoint online modern view where I'm using Site pages to add the content on the portal. 
I want to hide the title of the site page at the top like we use to do in on-premise version by adding CSS or script. Is there any way through which I can achieve this ?

Any help on this would be appreciated !

Thanks[image: Attached is the Image for Reference]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this using OOTB capabilities. However I would recommend below things:

1. If you want to hide the page title from only fixed number of pages (say only 4-5 pages) then I will recommend you to use [Modern Script Editor](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor) created using SPFx and adding the CSS to hide the page title.
2. If you want to hide the page title from **all modern pages** then I would recommend you to use Application customizer to inject the CSS on modern pages.

[Inject Custom CSS on SharePoint Modern Pages using SPFx Extensions](https://tahoeninjas.blog/2018/05/08/inject-custom-css-on-sharepoint-modern-pages-using-spfx-extensions/)

Comment: Hi @Muskan, have you tried this suggestions? Does this answers your question? If Yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that it will not be shown in unanswered questions list.